# Application crashes when ImageView loads image

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, imageview, android-framelayout

i have an application that loads a new image when the ImageView is clicked,
but it crashes and gives me error.
Can anyone help me out here?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView page;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    page = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Page);
    page.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            page.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            page.setImageResource(R.drawable.ap2);


        }
    });

}
```

}

I have tried converting the image to bitmap, and that doesn't work either.
My logCat keeps sending me the OutOfMemoryException and cannot load the image when i click on the ImageView.
Maybe my xml is bad structured? `

```
  <FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/Layout"
    >
 <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient3"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ap1"
    android:id="@+id/Page"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dip"
       android:layout_gravity="center|top"
       >
<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:src="@drawable/sound_on"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dip"
    android:id="@+id/Sound"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="95dip"
    android:src="@drawable/share"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:id="@+id/Share"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

`
Oh, and images are the proper size, like 700kb, not more.
Thanks!!

Comment: What is the resolution of the image you want to load?

Comment: It's high, about 1665x2550 does it matter? Because i use scaleType just for those reasons...

Comment: And for which resolution you are loading that image, I mean mdpi, hdpi or xhdpi?

Comment: hdpi... But does it matter?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that you are trying to load image which is very large according to your screen size of device and hence `OutOfMemoryException` is occurring. So, its better to crop or resize your image according to screen size resolution of your device.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks!!! So i should make it in 3 sizes, so that it can load on all the devices ( mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi ), right?